# Cannot save a file to devices Download folder using getExternalFilesDir()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I spent hours trying to solve this problem and got nowhere!
I am trying to save magnetometer data to csv file.
I am using FastCSV library.
Initially I used getExternalStoragePublicDirectory to save the file to the Downloads directory in my phone.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");
```

But since its been depreciated I used

```
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");
```

I get a toast message saying that my file is saved in the memory but I cannot find them when I look for them in my phone's Download location. Instead they are stored in my phone's Android directory.

Here's the code:

```
private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private View.OnClickListener listenerStopButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(recording == true)
            {
                recording = false;

                counter = 0;

                String value = fileIDEdit.getText().toString();

                stateText.setText("Recording Stopped");
                stateText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

                if (storagePermitted((Activity) context)){
                    csvWriter = new CsvWriter();
                    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");
                    //File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");

                    try {
                        csvWriter.write(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, magneticData);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File is recorded in memory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                        Log.d("Error", io.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing to save. Recording was not started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
```

This code checks for permission:

```
private static boolean storagePermitted(Activity activity){
        // Check read write permission
        Boolean readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        Boolean writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (readPermission && writePermission){
            return true;
    }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);

        return false;
}
```

Please let me know how can I use `getExternalFilesDir()` to save the file to Downloads directory!

Comment: "I cannot find them when I look for them in my phone" -- where are you looking? If you are trying to look for them in the system-supplied top-level `Downloads/` directory, then that is not where you are writing it. You are writing in `Android/data/.../files/Downloads/`, where `...` is your application ID.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! I did not know that. But what I want is to save the files to my device's download folder. How can I make the possible? That's my main question

Comment: Use [`MediaStore.Downloads`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html).