# Android Intent Chooser not able to open file in some cases

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to download a file to the `Downloads` directory and then view it when the user wants to open it. I am able to save the file to the downloads directory, but the problem arises when I try to view it using an `Intent Chooser`. At first, I saw the file gets saved with the path: `storage/emulated/0/Download/filename` but I wasn't aware how to access this path for different versions of devices, so I got the answer for this question from the question i posted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156920/how-to-get-path-storage-emulated-0-download-file-name-mime-type-for-android-10).

Now, I am able to view the file as well since I'm aware of the `filename`, it's `mimetype`, and the `path` from the above explanation. But, the problem is, I am only able to view the file via the `Intent Chooser` for devices like `Google Pixel` and `Samsung m 30s` running on `Android 10`, and when I tried for devices like `Realme 3 Pro`, `Oneplus 6` and some `MI` device that were also running on `Android 10`, after an app is selected from the `Intent Chooser`, instead of opening the file on these devices it tries to open the file but then jumps back to my app without opening the file. For devices below `Android 10` the problem doesn't seem to exist to me.

The code for my `DownloadRepository` and `MainActivity` can be found in the `Github gists` [here](https://gist.github.com/Mehul-Bisht/8f77e63f5bc05d453a7e001b7b52bf92) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Mehul-Bisht/f157339cc4f1ff97d15b32d4c44e120d) respectively.

I am currently not attaching code for the `FileProvider` in the `Android Manifest` and the `provider_paths` in the `XML` since it is working for some devices but I can attach that too if needed :)

**EDIT**

here is my `Android Manifest` and the `path for FileProvider`:

> Android Manifest permissions and FileProvider

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

> file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="downloads"
    path="/Download" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Intent chooser is used to open the file .
You can use Intent(ACTION_VIEW) and set its data and type with flags

Hope this answers might help
[ACTION_VIEW intent for a file with unknown MimeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype/6381479)

Comment: Well, did you open the Gist for `MainActivity` that I had linked? It already uses `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with a specified `mimetype` but it works for some devices only. I have tested and found the problem only for real devices running on `Android 10`.